# SQLITE - If a column is null then the value in another column is 0

Tags: sql, sqlite, case, sql-null

I have two columns in a table. The table name is constructed with inner join and group by, let's call this table `Joined`. It has two columns `Present` and `Score`. If `Present` is null then, I want to assign 0 to the `Score` value.

```
+------------+--------+-------------+------------+--------+
| Student_Id | Course | ExamDate    |  Present   | Score  |
+------------+--------+-------------+------------+--------+
|       1    | Math   | 04/05/2020  | Yes        | 45     |
|       2    | Math   | 04/05/2020  | NULL       | 90     |
|       2    | Math   | 04/05/2020  | NULL       | 50     |                     
+------------+--------+-------------+------------+--------+
```

What I have up to now is

```
SELECT DISTINCT StudentID ,Course, ExamDate, Present, Score
CASE Present ISNULL
Score = 0
END
    FROM Joined
```

I need the distinct because the inner join can give me some repetitions. What I need is

```
+------------+--------+-------------+------------+--------+
| Student_Id | Course | ExamDate    |  Present   | Score  |
+------------+--------+-------------+------------+--------+
|       1    | Math   | 04/05/2020  | Yes        | 45     |
|       2    | Math   | 04/05/2020  | NULL       | 0     |
+------------+--------+-------------+------------+--------+
```

It feels very very wrong to me but I haven't been able figure out how to do it with one query. How can I do it?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Thank you, I added the example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If Present is null then, I want to assign 0 to the Score value.

The `case` expression goes like:

```
select 
    present,
    case when present is null 
        then 0 
        else score 
    end as score
from ...
```

You don’t tell what to do when `present` is *not* `null` - so this returns the original `score`.

It is unclear why you would need `distinct`. If you were to ask a question about the original query, which seems to produce (partial) duplicates, one might be able to help fixing it.

Comment: I taught you could OR it but that doesn't work. NULL OR 0 returns 0. Any shorthand for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below -

```
SELECT DISTINCT StudentID ,Course, ExamDate, Present, Score,
CASE when Present IS NULL
then 0 else score END as scoreval
FROM Joined
```